# How do you send a User defined class object over a tcp/ip network connection in java?

Tags: java, networking, user-defined-types

This is an example of a user defined class I'd like to send from a client application to a server application:

```
class dataStruct implements Serializable{
    byte data;
    int messageNum;
    public void setData(byte datum, int messageNumber){
        data=datum;
        messageNum=messageNumber;
    }
}
```

How do you send a user defined class over a tcp/ip connection in java?

What types of streams can I use to accomplish this (if I'm sending more than just text)?

Can I pass a full object via a socket stream, or will I always have to cast it after it has been passed via a stream?

I'm writing a server/client application, and I've only been able to find tutorials with examples of primitive types or strings being passed over a network connection - not user defined types.

Your help and direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use JAXB over HTTP. After all it's 2011. Don't punish yourself.

Comment: @Kevin: This is only helpful if the server already is (in) an HTTP server.

Comment: @Paulo: That's true, it's about a 2-3 hour investment to switch the server to HTTP if you use spring-mvc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ObjectOutputStream on the sending side and an ObjectInputStream on the receiving side.

To be a bit more clear, here is an example (without any exception handling).

sending side:

```
dataStruct ds = ...;
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(ds);
oos.close();
```

receiving side:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object o = ois.readObject();
if(o instanceof dataStruct) {
   dataStruct ds = (dataStruct)o;
   // do something with ds
}
else {
   // something gone wrong - this should not happen if your
   // socket is connected to the sending side above.
}
```

So yes, you have to cast at the receiving side so the compiler knows the right class. (The casting does not change the class of the object, only changes the compiler's knowledge of it.)

This Serialization is also usable to save objects to a file.
Of course, this gives only interoperability to Java, if you have a non-Java partner, you might want to use a custom serialization protocol, or some XML-based format.

Comment: This assumes the class is known on the client and server side.

Comment: Yes, of course. If it is not known, you either need to make it known (like RMI does), or think about what is left to transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Let the objects implement the `Serializable` marker interface, and then transfer the objects using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`. When the object comes out on the other end, it will be via the `readObject()` method on `ObjectInputStream`, which returns `Object`, so yes, you will need to cast it to the proper type.